# replace System.out.println with variable outside of class groovy soapui

Tags: groovy, soapui

i have the below code from git which works 100% in eclipse. It spits out the excel file into a Xml format on the console. When I copy/paste this into a soapUI Groovy script and hit play, I don't see anything happen. I've tried replacing the `println` with `log.info` with no avail so i've attempted to return the xml into a variable but I can't figure out how to do this, as it looks like it needs to happen outside of the class --> to which I'm confused as to how to get the info from the `main` to the testCase property. I've also tried using the `testRunner` variables from inside the `main` and inside the `class` as getters and setters but...well errors, errors and more errors lol.

Thanks for any feedback

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*
import java.io.*



class GroovyExcelParser {
  //http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator

  def parse(path) {
    InputStream inp = new FileInputStream(path)
    Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);

    Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

    Iterator<Row> rowIt = sheet.rowIterator()
    Row row = rowIt.next()
    def headers = getRowData(row)

    def rows = []
    while(rowIt.hasNext()) {
      row = rowIt.next()
      rows << getRowData(row)
    }
    [headers, rows]
  }

  def getRowData(Row row) {
    def data = []
    for (Cell cell : row) {
      getValue(row, cell, data)
    }
    data
  }

  def getRowReference(Row row, Cell cell) {
    def rowIndex = row.getRowNum()
    def colIndex = cell.getColumnIndex()
    CellReference ref = new CellReference(rowIndex, colIndex)
    ref.getRichStringCellValue().getString()
  }

  def getValue(Row row, Cell cell, List data) {
    def rowIndex = row.getRowNum()
    def colIndex = cell.getColumnIndex()
    def value = ""
    switch (cell.getCellType()) {
      case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
        value = cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString();
        break;
      case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
        if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
            value = cell.getDateCellValue();
        } else {
            value = cell.getNumericCellValue().toInteger();
        }
        break;
      case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
        value = cell.getBooleanCellValue();
        break;
      case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
        value = cell.getCellFormula();
        break;
      default:
        value = ""
    }
    data[colIndex] = value
    data
  }

  def toXml(header, row) {
    def obj = "<object>\n"
    row.eachWithIndex { datum, i ->
      def headerName = header[i]
      obj += "\t<$headerName>$datum</$headerName>\n"
    }
    obj += "</object>"
  }

  public static void main(String[]args) {

    def filename = 'RaNdOmxlsxFile.xslx'

    GroovyExcelParser parser = new GroovyExcelParser()

    def (headers, rows) = parser.parse(filename)
    System.out.println 'Headers'
    System.out.println '------------------'
    headers.each { header ->
      System.out.println header
    }
    System.out.println "\n"
    System.out.println 'Rows'
    System.out.println '------------------'
    rows.each { row ->
      System.out.println parser.toXml(headers, row)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically multiples ways to achieve the same:

1. You should be able to see it the log files of *soapui*.
2. Otherwise, open command prompt -> go to *SOAPUI_HOME/bin*, run *soapui.bat/.sh* file and run groovy script you should be able to see the output in the command window console.
3. Copy the code from main method and put it out side of the class then replace `System.out.println()` with `log.info` and remove main method from the class. Then run the *groovy script*.

Hoping that you only wanted to see the output text.

Comment: Rao, thanks :) I tried #3 and its working just the way i need it to now :)